# Eliminating chapter headings

Tags: sectioning

Is it possible to eliminate the display of the `\part` and `\chapter` commands? For instance, I want TeX to keep track of my parts and chapters, but I don't want there to be any visual indication that a new chapter has begun. (My thought is to indicate sections using the headers, somewhat like in a Beamer presentation.)

Comment: It should be possible with `titlesec, but how do you know you're in another chapter then?

Comment: I'm using `titlesec`, but it wasn't obvious how to do it (to me at least). As to the document, I'm putting a breadcrumb-like indication of the document structure in the header instead.

Comment: You can try loading `titlesec` with option `explicit` and  code `\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{}` to see the result. I guess  the only visual indication of anew chapter will be in section numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough then to advance the counters?

Comment: @Bernard That does indeed remove the title, but the `\part` command still creates a (blank) page. (I believe there is also extra whitespace where `\chapter` was. I tried `\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` but to no effect.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's actually the part and chapter titles that I want. What's going into the part and chapter headings reflect a hierarchical organization, but there is no linear logic to the order of the parts and chapters, so it doesn't make sense to show the numbers.

Comment: Your description is rather unclear. Better make a sensible minimal example along with the wanted input and output. But if you don't want a display it imho doesn't make much sense to use a package like titlesec whose main purpose is to adapt the display.

Comment: It sounds as though you simply want unnumbered parts (`\part*{...}`) and chapters (`\chapter*{...}`).